# Cut address strings (Google Places API) in pieces and add to array

Tags: php, regex, google-places-api

I'm using the Google Place API to lookup addresses.
Some output examples:

```
Laag-Beugt 2 C, 5473 KB Heeswijk Dinther, Nederland
Industrieweg 36, 8091 AZ Wezep, Nederland
Rijakkerweg 7, 5741 RR Beek en Donk, Nederland
Antoon van Hooffplein 1, 6816 SH Arnhem, Nederland
Lingewal 2A, 6681 LJ Bemmel, Nederland
Lekdijk 120, 3999 NX Tull en Het Waal, Nederland
Concordialaan 2, 4874 NZ Etten-Leur, Nederland
Tibsterwei 4B, 9131 EG Ee, Nederland

Besser Str. 45, 34281 Gudensberg, Duitsland
Fabriekstraat 2, 9470 Denderleeuw, België
```

Now I want to cut these strings into pieces and put them in arrays like:

```
Array
(
    [adres] => Laag-Beugt 2C //No space between the 2 and the C
    [postcode] => 5473 KB
    [plaats] => Heeswijk Dinther
    [land] => Nederland
)

Array
(
    [adres] => Lekdijk 120
    [postcode] => 3999 NX
    [plaats] => Tull en Het Waal
    [land] => Nederland
)
Array
(
    [adres] => Tibsterwei 4B
    [postcode] => 9131 EG
    [plaats] => Ee //Shortest cityname in the Netherlands
    [land] => Nederland
)

Array
(
    [adres] => Besser Str. 45
    [postcode] => 34281
    [plaats] => Gudensberg
    [land] => Duitsland
)

Array
(
    [adres] => Fabriekstraat 2
    [postcode] => 9470
    [plaats] => Denderleeuw
    [land] => België
)
```

Since there's no comma between the 'postcode' (zipcode) and the 'plaats' (city), I can't use `explode`. The output will be like:

```
Array
(
    [adres] => Laag-Beugt 2C
    [postcode] =>  5473 KB Heeswijk Dinther
    [plaats] =>  Nederland
)
```

In the Nederlands a zipcode is in this format `1234 AA`, so I could use a regex to place a comma after two consecutive capitals, but the zipcodes in Belgium are in `1234` format and in Germany in `12345`. So i'm a little stuck here..

Someone who can help?

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts too..

Comment: @Uchida I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode function to make it in array

```
$rowAddress="Laag-Beugt 2 C, 5473 KB Heeswijk Dinther, Nederland";
$arr=explode(',',$rowAddress);

$add['adres']=$arr[0];
$add['postcode']=$arr[1];
$add['plaats']=$arr[2];
echo '<pre>';
print_r($add);
```

Comment: Explode is useless in this case because between `5473 KB Heeswijk Dinther` (postcode, plaats (zipcode, city)) there's no comma.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most beautiful and efficient piece of code, but it works.

If someone can enhance it, please do.

```
function addressArray($address) {

    $addressArray = explode(', ', $address);
    $headers = array('adres', 'postcode', 'plaats', 'land');

    if ($addressArray[2] == 'Nederland' || $addressArray[2] == 'Duitsland' || $addressArray[2] == 'België') {

        if ($addressArray[2] == 'Nederland') {
            $replace = preg_replace('/(\S+\s+\S+)\s/', '$1, ', $addressArray[1], 1);
        }

        if ($addressArray[2] == 'Duitsland'|| $addressArray[2] == 'België') {
            $replace = preg_replace('/(\S+)\s/', '$1, ', $addressArray[1], 1);
        }

        $replaceArray = array(1 => $replace);

        $replace = array_replace($addressArray, $replaceArray);
        $addressString = implode(', ', $replace);

        $newArray = explode(', ', $addressString);

        return array_combine($headers, $newArray);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```